# SPLongOperation only starts at operation end

Tags: application-pages, modal-dialog, splongoperation

I'm using an AppPage showed up in a ModalDialog and when I click on a button action I try to start a SPLongOperation process, but it only shows the processing panel right before it ends.

here is the code:

```
protected void CustomBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SPLongOperation.BeginOperation beginOperation = delegate(SPLongOperation operation)
                                            {
                                                operation.LeadingHTML = "Please wait while the operation is running.";
                                                operation.TrailingHTML = "Running stuff that takes time.";
                                                operation.Begin();

                                                //My Long Operation Code

                                                operation.EndScript("window.frameElement.commitPopup();");
                                            };
        SPLongOperation.Begin(beginOperation);
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException) {/* Thrown when redirected */}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

the prime idea is to lock the app page and then give back some feedback messages.

**any correction or alternative approach is welcome!**

spregards

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same behaviour where the panel only shows when processing ends. In my development environment the panel shows, the process takes a long time, and then the user is redirected. On our production environment the process takes a long time, then the panel shows and is immediately redirected, which I think is the problem you were having? Did you solve it?

Comment: Rob, are both enviromments with the same installed SP version?

Comment: Both are Server 2010 installs on Windows Server 2008. I can backup and restore both ways so I assume they are patched to the same version as well?

Comment: This situation occours, in my scenario, cause the installed versions were different (Standard and Enterprise). But actually I didn't find out what is the specific diff between them that results in that behavior. FYI: works with Standard SP version

Comment: Curious, both the environments in question have the same editions installed i.e. SharePoint Foundation 2010, SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise & Office Web Companions 2010 (as per the SKUs listed by 'get-spfarm | select Products'). The only difference is the dev environment has Project Server 2010 too, though I can't imagine that enables the SPLongOperation. Thanks for the info fallout, if I find anything further interesting I'll update here.

Comment: Did you ever find any solution for this? Having the same problem with SharePoint 2013. Starting fiddler seems to have weird effects on this, so maybe something to do with proxies? Fiddler seems to have fixed the issue when browsing locally my dev environment, but when browsing from another machine the loading view still won't show up...

Comment: this issue was 2010-related, the different behavior was a resulting of different SP versions (SPS / SPF). 
However, I'm actually running the same code in 2013 and, so far, has always work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually use it is something like this:

```
protected void CustomBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    using (var operation = new SPLongOperation(this.Page))
    {
        try
        {    
            operation.LeadingHTML = "Please wait while the operation is running."; 
            operation.TrailingHTML = "Running stuff that takes time."; 
            operation.Begin(); 

            //My Long Operation Code 

            operation.EndScript("window.frameElement.commitPopup();"); 
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException) {/* Thrown when redirected */} 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(ex.ToString()); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Jakob, but even with that approach I not even see the processing panel. I don't really understand what's wrong.

Comment: I've just tested this code in a webpart using Thread.Sleep(3000) as my long operation and it works perfectly

Comment: You are right. Actually also my code is working just fine, I just notice that when I made an deploy to a new environment. I'm still try to find the cause of it not working in the other environment...thanks so much for trying to helping me out with this.